# Javascript code not downloaded on hitting the URL "http://localhost:5000/signalr/hubs" in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr

I am create an SignalR server in .net core 3.1.

I added these few lines of code in startup to enable my server:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSignalR();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

    ...
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>("/msgs");
        });
    }
```

My Hub class looks like this:

```
  public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public MyHub()
    {

    }
    public void SendMsg()
    {
          Clients.All.SendAsync("MsgFromServer", notificationCount);
    }

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        // some login
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
      // some logic
    }       
}
```

When I launch the application, I get a message stating the application is running in port 5000 in my console window.

I see in many sites that on appending `signalr/hubs` to the hosted URL, I will be getting the java script  code downloaded, which indicates SignalR server is running successfully. But when I hit the browser with the following URL `http://localhost:5000/signalr/hubs`, I get:

> HTTP 404 error - Page not found.

When I hit `http://localhost:5000/msgs`, I get a response stating:

> Connection ID required

What is it that I am missing here?

Comment: From [the getting-started documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) it looks like /signalr/hubs has changed in the .Net Core SignalR, and the scripts are served from /js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js now, which you have to set up yourself.

Comment: Thanks Rup. Yes.. as you mentioned on hitting "http://localhost:5000/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js" i get a js file downloaded. But I believe this is not a proxy file which I can make use of in my another client project. How can I get the proxy file.